# APIから結果を取得するPythonプログラムの処理速度を上げたい

Tags: python, python-requests

#### 解決したいこと

初めてちゃんとしたコードを書いたのですが、実行に5分もかかることがあり、書き方次第でもっと早くできるところがあるんじゃないかと思い質問させていただきました。

#### プログラムの概要

クラッシュロワイヤルというゲームのAPIを取得し、必要な情報を取り入れ、pandasのデータフレームを作成するという流れです。

#### 実際のコード

```py
#クラロワAPIからプロ選手の情報を取得するプログラム
import time
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

access_key = "ここでは省略"

URL = 'https://api.clashroyale.com/v1'

#選手名とパスを結合する辞書を作成
dic={"みかん坊や":"%232VYJYJ09","天GOD":"%232G0QUGLU","kota":"%23889VQ8JP","RAD":"%238QRCJQ9Y","ライキジョーンズ":"%2398Q8LPQ9",
    "Jack":"%23YRVL9U98","きたっしゃん":"%23P8RLYOV9","だに":"%238LJVVGJP","けんつめし":"%23PQRR0CG9",
    "Rorapolon":"%239JPRJ9R","焼き鳥":"%232Y8GL0V2","ユイヒイロ":"%23R2GRQPCJ","Blossom":"%238Q20LRC8Y","kk19212":"%23RU2CC2LG",
    "れいや":"%232LRVG0C8","HANE×HANE":"%238Y088VU8U","Lewis":"%238Q020U0U","ピラメキ":"%232YGQGY92V","天ぷら":"%238Q2V2CGR","Scott":"%232Q98GVP9V"}

# 選手名を含むリストを作成
list= ["みかん坊や","天GOD","kota","RAD","ライキジョーンズ",
    "Jack","きたっしゃん","だに","けんつめし",
    "Rorapolon","焼き鳥","ユイヒイロ","Blossom","kk19212",
    "れいや","HANE×HANE","Lewis","ピラメキ","天ぷら","Scott"]

# 選手の基本情報を取得
def general_info(name):
    target_api = URL + "/players/"
    playerTag = dic[name]
    url = target_api+playerTag
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "cache-control": "max-age=60",
        "authorization": "Bearer  %s" % access_key}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    return data

__name__ == '__general_info__'


# 選手の対戦情報を取得
def battle_info(name):
    target_api = URL + "/players/"
    playerTag = dic[name]
    url = target_api+playerTag+"/battlelog"
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "cache-control": "max-age=60",
        "authorization": "Bearer  %s" % access_key}
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    return data

__name__ == '__battle_info__'


# 自分のデッキリストを作成（変数は選手名と何番目のデッキか））
def selfdeck_list(name,newnum):
    #decktype = battle_info(name)[0]["type"]
    #cardsname = battle_info(name)[0]["team"][0]["cards"][1]["name"]

    # 普通の書き方バージョン
    decklist = []

    for decknum in range(0,25):
        decktype = battle_info(name)[decknum]["type"]

        for numindeck in range(0,8):
            cardsname = battle_info(name)[decknum]["team"][0]["cards"][numindeck]["name"]
            decklist.append(cardsname)

    """内包表記バージョン?
    decklist = [ battle_info(name)[decknum]["team"][0]["cards"][numindeck]["name"] for decknum in range(0,25) for numindeck in range(0,8) ]
    decktype = [ battle_info(name)[decknum]["type"] for decknum in range(0,25)]"""

    return decktype[int(newnum)]
    return decklist[int(newnum*8):int(newnum*8+8)]
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start
    print ("elapsed_time:{0}".format(elapsed_time) + "[sec]")

selfdeck_list("Scott",0)


# 対戦相手のデッキリストを作成（変数は選手名と何番目のデッキか）
def opponentdeck_list(name, newnum):
    #decktype = battle_info(name)[0]["type"]
    #cardsname = battle_info(name)[0]["team"][0]["cards"][1]["name"]
    # 1つ目の[]は何試合目か、3つ目は8個の中の何番目

    """ 普通バージョン
    decklist = []

    for decknum in range(0,25):
        decktype = battle_info(name)[decknum]["type"]

        for numindeck in range(0,8):
            cardsname = battle_info(name)[decknum]["opponent"][0]["cards"][numindeck]["name"]
            decklist.append(cardsname)"""

    #内包表記バージョン?

    decklist = [ battle_info(name)[decknum]["opponent"][0]["cards"][numindeck]["name"] for decknum in range(0,25) for numindeck in range(0,8) ]
    decktype = [ battle_info(name)[decknum]["type"] for decknum in range(0,25)]

    return [decktype[int(newnum)], decklist[int(newnum*8):int(newnum*8+8)]]



#2.　デッキのdateframe作成
"""
columns1 = ["対戦種類","自デッキ","敵デッキ","勝敗"]

for number in range(0,25):
    player = "Scott"
    datas = selfdeck_list(player,number),opponentdeck_list(player,number)

deckdata = pd.DateFrame(data=datas,index=number,columns=columns1 )

print(deckdata)
"""


#3.　datesetの中に入れ、DateFrameを作成
"""
columns2 = ["クラン","タグ","現在トロ","最多トロ","チャレンジ名","デッキ"]

for player in list:
    dataset = general_info(player)["tag"],dic[player],general_info(player)["trophies"],general_info(player)["bestTrophies"],battle_info(player,0)

generaldata = pd.DateFrame(data=dateset,index=list,columns=columns2)
print(generaldata)
"""
```

Comment: 1回辺りのAPIリクエストにはどの程度時間が掛かっていますか？ / APIは調査するのに時間がかかる（アクセスキーの申請が必要である）為、ご自身でどこがボトルネックなのかを調べると回答が得られやすくなります。

Comment: APIリクエスト自体にはほとんど時間がかからないのですが、
def selfdeck_list(name,newnum):などの関数を実行するととても時間がかかってしまいます…

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/189443

Comment: ほとんど時間がかからないとは、具体的には何ms程度でしょうか？ / 合わせて全体の実行時間もお教えください。

Comment: コードを見る限り、25*8=200回APIを叩く処理が走っており、一方それ以外の重い計算は無いようなので、所感としてはAPI実行部分にボトルネックがあるように見えます（1回のリクエストに100msだとしても、100ms*200=20s掛かるので）。

Answer (score 0):

コードを見る限り、25*8=200回APIを叩く処理(`battle_info(name)`)が走っており、一方それ以外の重い計算は無いようなので、所感としてはAPI実行部分にボトルネックがあるように見えます（1回のリクエストに100msだとしても、100ms*200=20s掛かるので）。

※マルチポスト先でも同様の回答で解決済みのようです。

---

<sup>この投稿は @PicoSushi さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54963/#comment58883_54963)などを元に 編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>